# java threads and mutual exclusion

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, monitor

I have the following classes to represent a banking system:

The class that is a monitor: BankAccount

```
public class BankAccount 
{
    private boolean isLocked = false;
    private int balance;
    private String name;
    private int nrWithdrawals;
    public  Transaction Transaction;

    public BankAccount()
    {
        this.balance = 300;
        this.name = "Bank Account";
    }

    public synchronized void  withdraw(Transaction tran)
    {
        while(!canWithdraw(tran))
        {
            try
            {  
                wait();
                System.out.println("Not enough money: ");                               
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        this.setBalance((this.getBalance() - tran.getBalance()));
        System.out.println("Remaining Balance is: " + this.getBalance());
    }


    public synchronized void depositMoney( )
    {
        while(this.getBalance() + 100 <= this.BankAccountLimit)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }

        this.setBalance(this.getBalance() + 100);
        System.out.println("Bank Account balance is: " + this.getBalance());
    }
}
```

A class(thread) called: User

```
public class User extends Thread
{   
    private final BankAccount account;
    private ThreadGroup threadGroup;
    private Transaction tran;
    private String bName;
    private String userName;

    public User(BankAccount acc, ThreadGroup group, String name)
    {
        super(group, name);
        this.account = acc
        this.userName = name;
        this.threadGroup = group;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
        {
            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(70);
            account.withdraw(tran);

            System.out.println(this.getUserName() + " is using the bankaccount");
            try
            {  
                sleep(2000);     
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
        } 
    }
}
```

A class(thread) called Manager

```
public class Manager extends Thread
{
    private final BankAccount account;
    private ThreadGroup threadGroup;
    private String managerName;

    public Manager(BankAccount acc, ThreadGroup tgroup, String name)
    {
        account = acc;
        threadGroup = tgroup;
        managerName = name;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            account.depositMoney();
            try
            {
                sleep(100);
                System.out.println("trying....");
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){} 
    }  
}
```

and a main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ThreadGroup users = new ThreadGroup("Users");
    ThreadGroup managers = new ThreadGroup("Managers");

    BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
    User user1 = new User(account, users, "User1");
    User user2 = new User(account, users, "User2");
    Manager manager = new Manager(account, managers, "Manager1");   
    user1.start();
    user2.start();
    manager.start();
}
```

What I would like to achieve would be something like this:

user1 or user2 start withdrawing money(each one try for a number of times). Lets say user1 starts first.

If there is not enough money wait until the manager deposits(tries to deposit three times or something likethis) some money and afterwards user1 resumes withdrawing money then after he finishes user2 starts withdrawing money.

The issues I have: 
How do I make sure that either user1 or user2 is the first thread to run.
Is it posible make a thread wait, execute another and resume the one that is waiting ?(make user1 wait, execute manager then resume user1 and then execute the remaining user?)

Comment: Yes, using fair Reentrant locks: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock%28boolean%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes you have done here.

1. Your balance is not thread safe. Two threads can alter it within Withdraw and depositMoney methods. So you can use a mutex, ReenterantLock as [bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810077/bot) explained.
2. If your execution ended up in wait(), either Withdraw or depositMoney then there is no way of getting out of it. To avoid that you can call notifyAll() after each withdraw or deposit.

Here is the sample code with the suggested alterations

```
public class BankAccount
    {
        private boolean isLocked = false;
        private int balance;
        private String name;
        private int nrWithdrawals;
        public  Transaction Transaction;
        private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public BankAccount()
        {
            this.balance = 300;
            this.name = "Bank Account";
        }

        public synchronized void Withdraw(Transaction tran)
        {
            lock.lock();
            while(!CanWithdraw(tran))
            {
                try
                {
                    lock.unlock();
                    System.out.println("Not enough money. Waiting for manager to deposit");
                    wait();
                    lock.lock();

                }
                catch( InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            this.setBalance((this.getBalance() - tran.getBalance()));
            notifyAll();

            System.out.println("Remaining Balance is: " + this.getBalance());
            lock.unlock();
        }


        public synchronized void depositMoney( )
        {
            lock.lock();
            while(this.getBalance() + 100 <= this.BankAccountLimit)
            {
                try
                {
                    lock.unlock();
                    wait();
                    lock.lock();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }


            this.setBalance(this.getBalance() + 100);
            notifyAll();
            System.out.println("Bank Account balance is: " + this.getBalance());
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a Exception in thread "Albert" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method) when the method hits notifyAll();

Comment: Thanks, it is a good starting point. One more question: in my code above you can see that each thread attempts to perform the withdraw/deposit three times. Can I lock it when the for loop begins and release it once the for loop is completed.? Right now i get something like : user1 withdraw, user2 withdraw (not enought balance) managerdeposit user1 withdraw user2 withdraw etc...

Comment: Hope you are trying to allow transaction support. If you want to do that then you should keep a object level lock. First you acquire the lock then do some transactions and then release the lock. If you do this then you don't really use any other lock or synchronization blocks. You can do by adding two methods, acquireLock() and releaseLock() in BankAccount class. But make sure that you don't wait if you don't have sufficient value.

Comment: I've managed to get a working version(only in some situations). If first user withdraws money and then second user start withdrawing money but there isn't enough then it will wait while the manager deposits money and then user2 will resume withdrawing money(this is good). But if user1 remains without money and waits and calls notyfy then user2 will acquire the bankaccount..but there isn't enough money so it will wait as well and the manager  acquires the bankaccount but nothing happens. the user threads have higher priority then the manager.

Comment: You can set priority on users by setting the priority using setPriority() method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority(int)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it posible make a thread wait, execute another and resume the one that is waiting

Yes. What you are referring to is a classic case of the producer-consumer problem.

You can use explicit synchronization by using the `synchronized` keyword. Use the `wait` method to make a thread release it's locks and use the `notify` method to notify threads that the lock is now available.

You can also use a [ReenterantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Comment: bot - if I want to lock the monitor until the thread does the for loop inside the run() ? Is it alright to put the lock there ? public void run() { lock.lock for(int i = 0; i< 3 ; i++) { do stuff; }  lock.unlock ?          or how would it be with synchronized and wait.